# Javascript alert cancel button not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm trying to set up a sequence of events so that when a user click on a radio button it triggers the form to submit. In addition, I want to give the user a java warning asking them to confirm their selection by click ok, then redirect to php page, or cancel and stay on current page and do nothing. This is what I have, but for some reason when user click cancel on alert in safari, the form still submits.

Is the radio onclick conflicting with the actual script? How would I add the alert to the script?

```
<form name="confirmForm" id="confirmForm" method="POST" action="update_confirm.php">

<div id="confirmGroup">

<input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Verify" class="verify" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');" >
<label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup1">Verify</label>

<input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good" class="good" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');" >
<label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup2">Good</label>

<input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad" class="bad" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');" >
<label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup3">Bad</label>

</div>
</form>
```

--

```
<script> 
    $("#confirmForm").change(function()
    {
    document.getElementById("confirmForm").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly, a form doesn't change, inputs do.  
Secondly, returning false when clicking inputs probably isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Please remember that `confirms` are useful, they are also considered very confronting, scary and/or unpleasant. If I'm confronted with to many confirms (or other dialogs) my user experience is not good. Only add them when really necessary. Like when somebody is about to delete something. Otherwise give the option to change their opinion or give ask for another confirmation on a new page that has the same layout to enhance the users experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `confirm` in your JQuery `change` event:

```js
$("#confirmForm").change(function() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure of your selection?')) {
    document.getElementById("confirmForm").submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="confirmForm" id="confirmForm" method="POST" action="update_confirm.php">

  <div id="confirmGroup">

    <input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Verify" class="verify" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');">
    <label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup1">Verify</label>

    <input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good" class="good" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');">
    <label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup2">Good</label>

    <input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad" class="bad" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');">
    <label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup3">Bad</label>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: should I remove the onclick event?

Comment: Just did. Ur code snippet worked great! Thank you!! I did have to remove the onclick, cause after ur snippet message was triggered, the onclick event occurred. Once I removed onclick, everything worked as planned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's working...

Check again your code.

```js
    $("#confirmForm").change(function()
    {
    document.getElementById("confirmForm").submit();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="confirmForm" id="confirmForm" method="POST" action="update_confirm.php">

<div id="confirmGroup">

<input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup1" value="Verify" class="verify" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');" >
<label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup1">Verify</label>

<input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup2" value="Good" class="good" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');" >
<label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup2">Good</label>

<input type="radio" name="email_confirm" id="emailGroup3" value="Bad" class="bad" onclick="return confirm('Update Email Status?');" >
<label class="emailGroup" for="emailGroup3">Bad</label>

</div>
</form>
```